How to properly search a collection and a relation in Mongo at the same time?
I’m trying to figure out how to properly search a collection and a relation at the same time?
Lets say I have Users setup like this:
{
  _id: ObjectId("1234"),
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Smith"
}

And Posts setup like this:
{
  _id: ObjectId("8877"),
 user: ObjectId("1234") 
 title: "My Post",
}

How could I do a search on posts that could grab any posts that match my query on post.title or user.firstName or user.lastName?
I’ve tried an aggregate with $lookup and have gotten it close. This narrows down the nested relation, but i’m not sure how to also check the current collection.
[
  {
    
          $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'user',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'user',
            pipeline: [
              {
                $search: {
                  compound: {
                    should: [
                      {
                        search: {
                          query: "Jim",
                          path: 'user.firstName',
                        },
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          },
  },
  { $unwind: '$user' },
]


If the lookup pipeline $search is working the way you want, after unwinding, the next step would be to check if the "user" field exists OR the title matches the query. Remember to use preserveNullAndEmptyArrays when unwinding.
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $search: {
            compound: {
              should: [
                {
                  search: {
                    query: "Jim",
                    path: "user.firstName"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$user",
      // preserve is required for OR-matching next
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { "user": { $ne: null } },
        // replace "john" with your search term
        { "title": "john" }
      ]
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground with your pipeline $search - playground itself does not have $search capabilities.
If you want only lowercase name matching rather than $search:
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $or: [
                { $eq: [{ $toLower: "$firstName" }, "john"] },
                { $eq: [{ $toLower: "$lastName" }, "john" ] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$user",
      // preserve is required for OR-matching next
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { "user": { $ne: null } },
        // replace "john" with your search term
        { "title": "john" }
      ]
    }
  }
])

A working Mongo Playground using lowercase name matching
Alternate to the above, Playground with all matching done after unwinding.

That works for the most part, but for some reason the last match makes it show no results. The only way I got it to work was if I comment out the { "user": { $ne: null } }, and the { "title": "john" } has to actually match something as well, otherwise I get no results. Any idea why the last match wouldn't work?

Are you sure it's not just a test data issue? Jim vs john. What results do you have after the $lookup and before the $unwind?

Apparently the pipeline was causing an issue. Doing all the matching in $match fixed the issue.

If that helped, read: What should I do when someone answers my question?, and about accepting and voting.
